# using multiple output from one sql query into another

Tags: sql

how sql query can be created for following
I have two table

fist table contain emp code and category like

```
paycode   category
12345     manager
23456     manager
23654     manager
78965     AM
56987     AM
58966     AM
```

and second table contain paycode and leave type taken and date

```
Paycode  leavetype  date
12345      sl      01-01-2017
12345      sl      02-01-2017
12345      sl      03-01-2017
12345      sl      04-01-2017

23456      EL      01-01-2017
23456      EL      01-01-2017
23456      EL      01-01-2017
23456      EL      01-01-2017
```

i want to select a category from first table and against each output i want to count number of a particular leave taken

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: With that sample table data, what is the expected result? (Formatted text please, not images.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
DECLARE @mytable TABLE
(paycode int,category nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO @mytable
VALUES

(12345,'manager'),
(23456,'manager'),
(23654,'manager'),
(78965,'AM'),
(56987,'AM'),
(58966,'AM')

DECLARE @mytable2 TABLE
(paycode int,leavetype nvarchar(50),DATEstamp date)

INSERT INTO @mytable2
VALUES

(12345 , 'sl','01-01-2017'),
(12345 , 'sl','02-01-2017'),
(12345 , 'sl','03-01-2017'),
(12345 , 'sl','04-01-2017'),
(23456 , 'EL','01-01-2017'),
(23456 , 'EL','01-01-2017'),
(23456 , 'EL','01-01-2017'),
(23456 , 'EL','01-01-2017')

Select a.Paycode,Category,count(b.leavetype) as Total from @mytable a
left join @mytable2 b on a.paycode = b.paycode
group by a.paycode,a.category
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked..And u just simplify the thing to test my query ..thanks a lot for this..

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT E.Paycode, E.Category, COUNT(C.leavetype)
FROM EMP E
LEFT JOIN CATEGORY C ON E.Paycode = C.Paycode
GROUP BY E.Paycode, E.Category
```